# Unable to change plot title for exponential model (from forecast)

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, forecasting

I have an ets object (obtained with the `ets()` function [from](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/ets) forecast) and want to plot it.

```
fit <- ets (myTimeSeries) # myTimeSeries obtained via ts()
plot (fit) # works fine
plot (fit, main="my title") # fails with error
```

The error is:

`Error in plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
  formal argument "main" matched by multiple actual arguments`

I don't understand what I need to do, the attribute is shown in the help.

My loaded packages (in case there is a conflict about which plot() implementation is called):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-29  forecast_5.4     timeDate_3010.98 zoo_1.7-11       ggplot2_0.9.3.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     fracdiff_1.4-2   grid_3.1.0       gtable_0.1.2    
 [6] labeling_0.2     MASS_7.3-31      munsell_0.4.2    nnet_7.3-8       parallel_3.1.0  
[11] plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     quadprog_1.5-5   Rcpp_0.11.1      reshape2_1.4    
[16] scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.0      tseries_0.10-32
```

Comment: Looks like there is somehow some conflict about what "main" means, can you  try removing the packages you aren't using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that would work if you really did want to add a title to a plot of the fit function specified in the question (tested with the USAccDeaths data):

```
> plot.ts(cbind(observed = myTimeSeries, level = fit$states[, 1], season = fit$states[, "s1"]), main = "New Title")
```